# Moderation attendence to edit rejection

Tags: feature-request, rejected-edits, moderators

When I suggest an edit and it gets rejected for obvious wrong reasons, I often get annoyed. I put energy in improving the questions or keeping the tags I am watching tidy. All I get is a (partial) reject from some random reviewer.

There seems to be no way in contacting the (diamond) moderator or any other higher instance that he is wrong or at least challenge his ruling. I would like to get a button, to ask for moderators (or any higher instance). Maybe the decision is taken back, when the reviewer takes a second look after he is acknowledged that his decision is challenged. At least he can learn that people don't share his view.

It is not only to keep the editors motivated, but also to sharpen the judgment of the reviewers.

Comment: You getting angry doesn't sound like a good reason to make a tool.  Remember, it takes more than one reviewer to reject edits; if your edits are getting rejected on a regular basis, you might want to re-evaluate your assumptions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, annoyed would be the right term.

Comment: Such questions are generally I think more useful with examples of edits that have been rejected that you feel shouldn't have been -- so that they can be responded to or decisions changed. As it stands, this question just looks like a bit of a rant, and getting angry at things on the Internet is rarely worth the typing. :)

Comment: @TZHX: It is more of a general question. I want a tool to handle such cases. Still, an example: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7600146 Review by Sai is a reject, he obviously did not see that I removed a tag, despite I wrote so in my comment. He has no cmake tag at all.

Comment: One reject doesn't stop your edit being made. And it looks like it's now actually been approved. I assume that Sai acts in good faith, going on the "Changes are either completely superfluous" for the text differences that appear in the question body before scrolling down the tags. Not long ago there was a "too trivial" reason that would have covered this -- but please be aware that you left several things in that post that could have been improved. Ideally, If you're going to edit a post, try and fix as many things as you can.

Comment: @usr1234567 I really don't get your point, approval or reject is a consensus on many reviewer to temperate human errors we can all do. Wishing to start a talk with the reviewer each time there's a reject vote sounds superfluous... (and you exemple is quite clear about this, 3 approval, 1 reject)

Comment: Still, there is no way to challenge wrong decisions. Everything else on StackOverflow can be challenged. But from your comments and the current score of my question, I assume you don't think this is worth the effort...

Comment: The problem you face is that the community already handles this: a single reject on one of your pending edits means nothing, it just means waiting a little longer for a decision. People who routinely guess "wrongly" are trapped (hopefully) by review audits that remove their ability to review suggestions and prompt them to learn the correct ways. You've demonstrated no reason why a new feature is required, and certainly not why this system needs intervention from a diamonded-mod (who could otherwise spend their time doing something which actually has an affect).

Comment: So, a [tag:feature-request] is going to be met with down-votes because people just don't think it's a feature that is needed.

Comment: Discovering that not *everybody* agrees with your moderator actions at SO is supposed to be a character-building experience.  Prepares you well for the time you reach 3000 rep and you don't get reviewed anymore.  You are not there yet.

Comment: Simple.  Get over 20k, and you can edit whatever the hell you want without it going into the review queue.  It's super sexy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixing typos are only really useful if they **actually clarify or help imporve readability of the question**. As such, fixing an `i` to `I` doesn't make the question any better, and so it would be at the reviewer's discretion to say 'is this edit really necessary?', and will or will not be accepted as an edit.

This is why **multiple reviewers will review your edit**. Of course, it would be one sided for a single user to reject or approve edit - and hence why this isn't the case.

Another point in your argument is that one user in 4 found this 'not helpful'. Realistically, since it only really takes 3 users to approve/not approve a edit, I don't think this warrants a 'bad review' button or option. After all, we're all human, and we can all make mistakes (not actually saying this is or isn't a mistake).

So always ensure your edit is **super-overly helpful**. That way, reviewers will have no reason to 'reject' the edit. But typo fixes are realistically one of the least of a reviewers concerns, unless it impacts on how **the question can be read and understood by more people**.

Your concern over 'I fixed a tag' **is, I believe, valid**. Whilst OP might not actually know if it 'is or isn't' related to their question, they have added it for a reason - and you've got to understand that. Maybe it is because they're using it in their work, or maybe they've picked the wrong one - again, it's up to the community to decide if it is or isn't helpful to have.

Unfortunately, I don't have the experience to call on that tag, since i have not actually heard of or used it.

But having a 'contact mod' button would be quite unproductive, IMHO, since they have a million and one different issues to be looking at, least of all really being 'editing typo' reviews, so I feel this feature would be quite unproductive. If you have a pressing concern, you could always try the 'chat' section of SO where some mods usually reside.

But remember, mods are **always** doing something productive, so having them look into 'small matters' would actually retract from their other work, such as helping the community and working here, on meta.

---

Also, in hindsight, your review *was* approved, and so this topic isn't ***really*** needed, since your question seems to be *'but what if...'*, rather than 'such and such has actually happened'

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there's no point questioning edit rejection or approval; whether the edit becomes accepted or rejected is not judged from one random user and that means multiple people usually think your edit does not contribute to the post's becoming easy-to-read, let alone that there is a rather high enough threshold on who can review such requests to avoid issues.

Getting angry or disturbed (however you many call it) is not the right way to deal with this; that post is hardly worth the time (at least in my opinion). It's actually more of a rage post, rather than a request or discussion post. You can always spend this time in doing something more productive, like editing more posts, but this time maybe more successfully, taking into consideration the feedback from this topic and the edit rejections.